# "Attempt to redirect activation..." exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, remoting

My application has an HTTP channel to run a method on a remote computer.  I'm able to do that with one computer by using the line:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(
   typeof(RemoteObject), uri);
```

I also need to run another method on another computer. So I used the same line as above but changed the URI to the name of the other remote computer. However, I am getting this `RemotingException`:

> Attempt to redirect activation of type 'RemoteClass.RemoteObject, RemoteObject'
>   which is already redirected.

I've done some research on this exception but haven't found too much information about it. I've looked at the documentation for the exception, but don't really understand it. I tried to find the cause of the error, and learned that if I change the parameter `typeof(RemoteObject)` such that `typeof()` is applied to an object of a different type, it works fine. But I still need to use `RemoteObject` as the type in order to run a method from that class. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Also,, were you aware that remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF? It's possible that the workaround is "use WCF".

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  Thanks for the response, I was not aware that WCF was more favorable.  I'll look up WCF, and see what I can do about it.  Does anyone else know if there might be another solution?  Ideally, if there was a way to do it with remoting, I would do that because it would save time (I hope).  But I'll learn some WCF in the meantime, and get started with WCF if no solutions or ideas are posted.

Comment: To be clear, Remoting is quite obsolete. You should really spend no time working with it.